# Entity Framework 5 log database changes at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In an ASP.NET 4.5 C# Entity Framework 5 Code First project I'd like to log the changes being made in the database at runtime (the logging has to be done in the asp.net app, not at the database). Previously, the SQL statements were built by the code, and those statements were simply logged. Now with EF, the object is retrieved via linq to entities, modified and

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

is being called. My first idea was to retrieve the actual SQL statements that EF sends to the DB -- this seems to be rather complex, however. I've found many "solutions" for displaying the SQL during debugging, but no simple way for the code to retrieve it at runtime.

So I'm looking for any solution that can log the changes being made (either the SQL being sent to the DB [preferred], or some other form of textual representation of the changes made to the object), and that doesn't require the inclusion of a number of complex debug libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You should try FrameLog

https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/framelog/wiki/Home

It is not clearly stated but it supports Entity Framework 5

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on EF 4.5 so it may need to be tweaked a bit, but I find for debugging purposes the extension method written at the bottom of this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2a50ffd2-ed73-411d-82bc-c9c564623cb4/

Gives me the correct output of my entities.SaveChanges() call. It doesn't require any external libraries and since it's written as an extension method it won't clog up your code.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't apply to EF5 and DBContext.